# Push a dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Why the answer is undefined in the Second example?

```js
// First
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];
var newArr = arr[1];
newArr.push('Peter');
console.log(arr);

// Second
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];
arr.push([1]['Peter']);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What is `[1]['Peter']`?

Comment: JS doesn't have multidimensional arrays, you can only emulate those with nested arrays.

Comment: I'm trying to push the array at the second position and add the name 'Peter'!

Comment: You should do `arr[1].push('Peter')` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `[1]['Peter']` is trying to access a key named `Peter` from the array literal `[1]`. And it is `undefined`

Your code is equivalent to this:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];

var tempArray = [1];
var tempValue = tempArray['Peter'] // undefined

arr.push(tempValue);
console.log(arr);
```

You should change it to: `arr[1].push('Peter')`

Answer (score 1):

That syntax `[1]['Peter']` doesn't do what you might imagine. You're passing an input parameter. It doesn't reference the array pushing it into, it's completely independent. So you're effectively telling JavaScript to first create a new array (`[1]`), and then try to access an index called "Peter" from within it (`["Peter"]`), and then push that into the next free index in `arr`. Clearly that "Peter" index doesn't exist within the new array, which is why it outputs `undefined`.

Instead you'd have to write it like this, so it pushes to the existing array, which is itself at index `1` of `arr`:

```js
// First
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];
var newArr = arr[1];
newArr.push('Peter');
console.log(arr);

// Second
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];
arr[1].push('Peter');
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
arr.push([1]['Peter']);
```

But an array which contains a single element, `1`, does not have the property `Peter`. Arrays generally do not have non-numeric properties (other than those on `Array.prototype` and `Object.prototype`)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
var arr = [
  [1, 4, 6],
  ['alex']
];
arr[1].push('Peter');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this produces a different result than the first example in the question. Both examples are supposed to produce the same output (but using different syntax).

Comment: I mistakenly understood his "second position" to be the second index in array. Let me correct it

Comment: ok that's better. Now you should probably add an explanation, otherwise you've just produced the same code as the other answers, but without giving any reason for it. That makes the other answers are superior because they have additional useful content. Working code is great, but it's not so useful unless we can learn from it as well.